# Oracle APEX validate Input during Data Load with Transformation Rule

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

In **APEX**, when performing a **Data Load** (e.g. upload of a csv file into APEX application), is it possible to **validate input** data using a transformation rule?

For example, suppose to upload data about cars that have been sold this month.
The target table has the column car_manufacturer and num_car_sold.

The column car_manufacturer must accept only three values, say ('A1', 'A2', 'A3'). 
In a *pseudo PLSQL*, just to give an idea:

```
IF :car_manufacturer IN ('A1, A2, A3') then :car_manufacturer else <error>
```

How can I check this in the upload phase? Is it possible to use a transformation rule, in order that if it fails, it returns an error message? Other ways?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put a constraint on the table definition as per the other answer, or if you only want the error message for when the Data Load is used, you can use a Table Lookup.

1. Go to **Shared Components** -> **Data Load Definitions**
2. Open the Data Load Definition that you want to edit
3. **Create Table Lookup**
4. Select the column (e.g. car_manufacturer)
5. Set the **Table Lookup** attributes to a table that contains the list of valid values (you'll need either a table or a view for this)
6. Leave **Insert New Value** set to **No** (*If set to 'No' (the default) then a new record will not be created in the lookup table if the lookup column value(s) entered do not already exist. If set to 'Yes' then a record will be created in the lookup table using the upload column(s) and the Upload Key Column will be retrieved from the newly created record.*)
7. Set **Error Message** to the message you want to return if a match is not found.

Comment: If the lookup fails, it returns an error message, but it also prevents the record to be uploaded. That's the expected result!

Answer (score 1):

How about having a check constraint on the table for the column "car_manufacturer"?

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_CAR_MANUFACTURER
CHECK ( CAR_MANUFACTURER in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3'));
```